# MySQL query from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope I am not breaking any rules with this post.
I got a table (in an instacart database) called order_products which has columns order_id and product_id describing which products are bought in each order.

Below is the CREATE TABLE

```
-- Name: order_products; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.order_products (
    order_id integer NOT NULL,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    add_to_cart_order integer,
    reordered integer
);
```

Below is a data sample as requested

```
----------+------------+
| Order_id | Product_id |
+----------+------------+
| 123      | 741        |
+----------+------------+
| 123      | 742        |
+----------+------------+
| 123      | 852        |
+----------+------------+
| 234      | 852        |
+----------+------------+
| 234      | 963        |
+----------+------------+
| 456      | 741        |
+----------+------------+
| 456      | 742        |
+----------+------------+
| 456      | 201        |
+----------+------------+
| 456      | 202        |
+----------+------------+
| 567      | 741        |
+----------+------------+
| 567      | 742        |
+----------+------------+
| 567      | 201        |
+----------+------------+
| 789      | 963        |
+----------+------------+
| 789      | 201        |
+----------+------------+
| 789      | 202        |
+----------+------------+
| 789      | 203        |
+----------+------------+
| 789      | 204        |
+----------+------------+
| 100      | 741        |
+----------+------------+
| 100      | 741        |
+----------+------------+
| 100      | 201        |
+----------+------------+
```

I want to query the pair that gets ordered the most together in a single order. In the above it would be the pair product id 741 and 742 given they are ordered 4 times together in one order.

I tried the following based on a self join

```
SELECT p1.product_id, count(p1.product_id), p2.product_id, count(p2.product_id)

FROM order_products AS p1, order_products AS p2

WHERE p1.order_id = p2.order_id

GROUP BY p1.product_id, p2.product_id

ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

To no luck, because it just returns the most bought products and their count twice, while I need the pair of products that are the most bought together.
I have no clue of to solve this, can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question with sample data

Answer (score 2):

You could use a self join and aggregate as the following: (this will return all pairs of products bought together)

```
Select OP1.product_id As Product1,
       OP2.product_id As Product2,
       Count(*) As NumberOfOrders
From order_products OP1 Join order_products OP2
On OP1.order_id = OP2.order_id And 
   OP1.product_id > OP2.product_id
Group By OP1.product_id, OP2.product_id
Order By Count(*) Desc
```

And if you want to return the *pair of products that are the most bought together*, you may use the `DENSE_RANK` function as the following:

```
Select Product1, Product2, NumberOfOrders
From
(
  Select OP1.product_id As Product1,
       OP2.product_id As Product2,
       Count(*) As NumberOfOrders,
       DENSE_RANK() Over (Order By Count(*) Desc) rnk
  From order_products OP1 Join order_products OP2
  On OP1.order_id = OP2.order_id And 
   OP1.product_id > OP2.product_id
  Group By OP1.product_id, OP2.product_id
) T
Where rnk = 1
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/p62Y7MS8).

Comment: Hey. One thing I dont understand quite well is the  OP1.product_id > OP2.product_id. 
Is it a "trick" not to display duplicates? Because if I instead do OP1.product_id <> OP2.product_id then it indeed displays duplicates.

Comment: Exactly, to not display duplicate pairs of products, this will guarantee that each product joined to another product only once.

Comment: Using `OP1.product_id <> OP2.product_id`, will join for example 741 with 201 and 201 with 741 which is a duplicate pair of products.